# Does anyone know where I can still download flex 3.5 sdk?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk

Does anyone know where I can still download flex 3.5 sdk? I just inherited a project which was developed in flex 3.5. I am having trouble configuring flash builder 4.6 to work with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get it here: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/flex_sdk_3.5.zip

Are you aware that latest version is 4.10? Available here: http://flex.apache.org/

Comment: You linked to 4.5 instead of 3.5. @Sunday: Just replace the 4 with a 3 in the URL and you're good to go.